# Retrieve users' password in Google Form textbox

Tags: html, google-app-engine, authentication

I would like to use Google Forms as a means for the users of my system to enter their login credentials to various system tools.

The reason this is important is because as their admin, I will need to manage various aspects of their tools.

Users are (rightly so) anxious of entering passwords in clear text boxes. What is the best method for retrieving such information in a safe and user-friendly manner?

Answer (score 1):

You should **NEVER** collect user credentials for 3rd party services, e.g. collecting username/password to Google accounts. Not even if this is a Google Apps account belonging to your organisation (note that google gives admins the ability to reset password but not to view it). Also, a lot of users are now using [two-step verification](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/), so collecting user credentials will not work.

If you need to access Google services in the name of the user, than you should look into [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2).

Comment: Thank you @Peter. What I'm asking for is indeed problematic, so let me clarify the need because there might be a better solution: in order to automate services in our organization, I need users to provide me with the API key for the different apps. Some of these cannot be retrieved via API, only manually. Since my users are non-technical I want to retrieve these for them. It's a one-time action. What would be the best method for me to do so, without violating their privacy?